# puppeteer : cannot load the whole child object of an html element

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer

In puppeteer , when i want to get the child of an element , i can get the values of a specific property (innerHtml, childElementCount...) but not the entire  child objects :

For example I can get all textContent of all tables

```
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const tables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table'));
        return tables.map(table => table.textContent)
     });
     console.log(data);
//print me [  "\n\t\tselection requirement\n\t\t", "\n\t\Area  \n\t\...]"
```

But when i want the whole table objects it returns me an array with null values:

```
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
         const tables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table'));
         return tables;
 });
 console.log(data);
// print me [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ]
```

Do you know how to get tha whole child objects?